# Abrir archivos descargados desde PHP

Tags: php, archivo

Estoy intentando abrir archivos con esta función. Para los archivos `*.pdf` y `*.txt` funciona bien, pero si el archivo es `*.doc` o `*.odt` al descargarlo y abrirlo aparecen caracteres extraños.

```
$filepath = '/var/download/prueba.doc';
    if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length:'.filesize($filepath));
            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
            readfile($filepath);
            exit();
        }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?, ¿hay alguna forma de poder abrir cualquier tipo de archivo una vez descargado?. No necesito abrirlos online, necesito poder descargarlos y una vez descargados poder leerlos en el PC.

Comment: Los navegadores no soportan la visualización de documentos de office, solo soporta archivos de texto plano o PDF, para visualizar documentos de office debes utilizar un visualizador de pago (No recuerdo ahorita un proveedor) aunq me parece que también podrías utilizar el visualizador de google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código parece correcto, por lo que el problema que sufres puede ser debido a dos motivos:

- El archivo PHP está codificado en UTF-8 con [BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes).
- Has dejado un espacio en blanco, retorno del carro, tabulación, carácter especial no imprimible, etc antes de la apertura de la etiqueta `<?php`.

En documentos pdf y txt no hay problema si hay algo al comienzo, pero los documentos doc, docx, odt, etc (los dos últimos son en realidad un archivo comprimido en zip) no permiten ningún agregado, abriéndose como texto una vez cargada la aplicación, mostrando su contenido bruto.

Te recomiendo que compruebes ambas cosas para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: En mi caso, un espacio en blanco antes de la apertura de php. Gracias

Comment: Un placer haber sido de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Para poder abrir un documento como word o excel online debes tener una libreria, acá te explica como sería para leer un excell con php:

http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/abrir-y-leer-archivos-excel-con-php-c38945l/

Espero te ayude en algo.

Comment: Se refiere a visualizarlos, no a tratarlos.

Comment: De igual manera, los archivos microsoft estan codificados de una manera diferente y creo que sin una libreria adecuada no los podrá visualizar.

Comment: No necesita una libreria si no que el cliente tenga un plugin en el navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencionaba el en comentario tendrías que utilizar un vizor para ver los documentos, en el siguiente ejemplo puedes utilizar el de google:

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://github.com/chrahunt/docx/blob/master/spec/fixtures/basic.docx?raw=true&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Espero te haya podido servir o al menos dar una guía.

Comment: No necesito leerlo online, me conformo con poder descargarlo y abrirlo en el pc, pero cuando lo abro en el pc, salen caracteres extraños. En el caso del iframe, como lo haría en php?

Comment: El navegador lo descarga de manera automatica, abres la url donde esta el archivo directamente en el navegador y listo sin necesidad de configurar le header, en pocas palabras puedes poner la url `www.example.com/docs/test.doc` en un vinculo `<a>` y listo

Comment: La idea es buena pero necesito que lo haga automaticamente  sin que exista un enlace donde el usuario tenga que pinchar. Es posible??