# ¿Cómo usar las variables de sesión?

Tags: php, session

Tengo un problema con las variables de sesión, pasa que las inicio en un archivo llamada `config.php` y hago el `include` desde el `index`, donde invoco fragmentos llamados **"Modulos"** dentro de este archivo de esta manera

`index.php`

```
<?php
include "configs/config.php";
include "configs/functions.php";

if(file_exists("modulos/".$p.".php"){
    include "modulos/".$p.".php";
}else{
    echo "El modulo solicitado no existe";
}
?>
```

En `config.php` tengo inicializado `@session_start()`;

Es decir lo invoca en cada fragmento el `index.php`

y cuando envió por la variable `$p` que es tipo `GET`, el modulo salir incluyo esto:

```
<?php
session_destroy(); //destruyo la sesion
redir("./"); //esto es una funcion de redireccionamiento personal
?>
```

Obviamente no inicio `session_start()` porque lo estoy incluyendo en el `index.php` antes de cargar este modulo.

Resulta ser de que esto aveces funciona y aveces no y no encuentro lógica, es decir, aveces inicia sesión y no me deja deslogear porque dice que no hay sesión iniciada, y aveces no me deja logear, o inclusive aveces se queda haciendo un bucle, porque en `login.php` si esta la sesión y me manda a `index.php`, pero en `index.php` no esta la sesion y me manda a `login.php`, ayúdenme por favor tengo ese problema. gracias de antemano comunidad StackOverflow!

Comment: Y en qué archivo haces el `session_start()`? o bueno más bien, coloca la parte donde haces lo inicias

Comment: en el archivo config.php al principio del archivo inicio @session_start(); y este archivo config.php lo incluyo en el index.php

Comment: No uses `@session_start()`. Quítale el `@` y usa `session_start()` a secas. Si inicias sesión en lugares variados recibirás una advertencia y podrás depurar ese problema. Recuerda iniciar las sesiones nada más iniciar el script PHP, no lo delegues en otros scripts y, si lo haces, hazlo en el primero que incluyas o requieras.

Comment: me salta esta advertencia: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/desarrollo/public_html/guestlaundry/admin/main/index.php:1) in /home/desarrollo/public_html/guestlaundry/configs/config.php on line 2

en el config.php tengio session_start()
y en index.php no tengo session_start() porque incluyo el config.php asi que config.php ya me incluiria ese codigo al principio

Comment: Tú mismo te has contestado. Mira el archivo `index.php` y verás que hay un espacio en blanco antes del `<?php` (o quizá sea el [BOM de UTF-8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193941/abrir-archivos-descargados-desde-php/194055#194055)).

Comment: En todo caso, sería mejor poner el código de ese archivo para ver como lo inicializas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disculpen, era una estupidez, habia un vinculo de redireccion en el boton que cuando se daba click en cierta parte, omitia el prceso y solo redireccionaba, por eso aveces funcionaba y aveces no.